# View built-in dataset from a package

Tags: r, arules

I have installed the packages **arules**. How can I view the built-in dataset as usual?

I tried:

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
Groceries
```

While it only offer me:

```
transactions in sparse format with
 9835 transactions (rows) and
 169 items (columns)
```

What is sparse format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
inspect(Adult)
inspect(Adult[1:10,1:10])

inspect(Groceries)
```